# Get last updated time at from WorkManager's Work/WorkInfo

Tags: java, android, kotlin, job-scheduling, android-workmanager

Is there any way to get finished or successful work timestamp?

`WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfosByTagLiveData(groupId)` this code gives `WorkInfo`.

I'm sure that `WorkManager` has timestamps to manage `Work`, but how to obtain it?

Comment: Why not write timestamps to disk at the end of your doWork() method yourself and then use  that? Or maybe even to some in-memory data structure if that is good enough for your needs.

Comment: Because I think that WorkManager API should be responsible for work information and not my Upload Entity.  If there is no such possibility with WorkManager - then yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm inspecting `androidx.work.workdb` file which is located at `/data/data/com.example/databases`. As of WorkManager 2.2.0 here're the columns that are present in the `WorkSpec` table:

- id (e.g. dbe0dcd0-ab76-4c1e-a963-be2135f41c3c)
- state (e.g. 2)
- worker_class_name (e.g. com.example.MyWorker)
- input_merger_class_name (mostly null, but also `androidx.work.OverwritingInputMerger`)
- input
- output
- initial_delay (e.g. 300000)
- interval_duration (e.g. 900000)
- flex_duration (e.g. 900000)
- run_attempt_count (e.g. 1)
- backoff_policy (e.g. 0)
- backoff_delay_duration (e.g. 30000)
- period_start_time (e.g. 1578901635581)
- num_retention_duration (e.g. 0)
- schedule_requested_at (e.g. 1578901635601)
- required_network_type (e.g. 1)
- requires_charging (e.g. 0)
- requires_device_idle (e.g. 0)
- requires_battery_not_low (e.g. 1)
- requires_storage_not_low (e.g. 0)
- trigger_content_update_delay (e.g. -1)
- trigger_max_content_delay (e.g. -1)
- content_uri_triggers

As can be deduced, there doesn't exist a field, which will reflect the timestamp when a particular work has been completed, because as per my understanding `WorkManager` doesn't need that field.

Hence, your only option is upon work's successful completion manually saving the timestamp using shared prefs or another SQLite table.

Comment: period_start_time (e.g. 1578901635581) looks like timestamp milliseconds timestamp, is it possible to teach it with code? Or it was different meaning

Comment: You are interested in work's successful finish time, aren't you? If so, cannot see how helpful might `period_start_time` be to you.

Comment: I see, but is there any way to access this variable "period_start_time"?

Comment: My guess is that you have to work with [`SqliteOpenHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper) in order to open specific `db` file (which is located under `/database/`) though at this point I'm not sure how it is achievable code-wise. Needs a bit investigation.